# What characteristics would agave nectar add to a wort?

Tags: flavor, adjuncts

I was thinking about adding agave nectar to my wort as an adjunct sugar, with the intent to add some tequila-like flavor. Does anyone have any experience with brewing with agave nectar and the flavors and characteristics it lends to the finished beer?

Comment: Agave nectar tastes nothing like tequila, to me anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only experienced it through a brewing buddy of mine.  He used it to 5% of the total fermentables, the results were lack luster.

It almost gets entirely fermented out so much of that character is lost.  And then you're only using a small percentage of it in the final product anyway.

The best way to get some tequila flavor is to add some at bottling.  Or soak some oak in tequila and dose it that way.

Comment: This is correct, and if you are looking for agave flavor, you'll have to kill the yeast after fermentation, add the agave, then force carbonate.

Answer (score 0):

It won't give your beer any "tequila" character at all. If you add it to the kettle, it will thin the body and add alcohol (assuming you add it to your recipe and don't replace other fermentables with it).  The only way to keep even a little bit of agave character would be to add it to the fermenter after about a week or so of initial fermentation.  even then, there will be little to no flavor from it.  I'm basing that on my own experience.